# Computer Science Theory with Haskell?

Tags: resource-request, cs-theory, complexity-theory

Do you know of any courses using Haskell to illustrate Computational Theory topics?

Comment: Is this for teaching yourself, or for teaching others?

Comment: It's for teaching others.

Comment: Could you add some more details about what you're looking for and why?  With so little to go on (and with a yes or no question), you are limiting your answers to a very narrow band.  I teach computational theory using Scheme, for instance.

Comment: You may find this useful http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~jtod/discrete-mathematics/

Comment: @BenI. Would you have any of the scheme+CT stuff accessible?

Comment: @Rusi It's not, though if you want to ping me in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/the-classroom), I'd be glad to describe what I do.

Comment: @BenI. Regular Languages, Context-Free Languages, Turing Machines, Decidability, Reductions, etc.